# Qt locale formatting of large currency (or number) on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to format a number as a currency and having problems.  I've tried with both the default locale and a specific one (like below). The number is formatted in scientific notation nonetheless.

```
QLocale::setDefault( QLocale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates) );
reportCost->setText( QString("$%L1").arg( cost ) );
```

The trouble is that as soon as I hit millions I get numbers like `$1.6473e6` rather than `$1,647,312`. How can I fix this?

Also,is there really no way to format a currency at all in Qt, like positioning the symbol and proper negative representation?

I cannot test on Windows right now so I don't know if this is Linux specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current implementation of `QLocale` falls short in a lot of these areas. See ["QLocale: It’s about time (and dates, and languages, and …)"](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/01/03/qlocale-its-about-time-and-dates-and-languages-and/) for an explanation of where this is headed in the future.

For now, a quick-and-dirty solution would be:

```
QString("$%L1").arg(amt, 0, 'f', 2);
```

If you need *real* localization, the [ICU libraries](http://site.icu-project.org/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do quick and dirty for now as I don't relish the idea of introducing yet another string class into the system. Though if I need more I will go to ICU.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but it's worth pointing out to anyone who stumbles across this that in Qt 4.8 and above, the first thing to try should be [`QLocale::toCurrencyString(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#toCurrencyString)